# Doubt in a particular extract from the newspaper "The Hindu"

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-request, word-meaning

I could not understand the analogy behind this particular paragraph taken from the Indian newspaper called "The Hindu".
The paragraph is given as follows:

> The Forest Department officer also speaks of an administrative gap."We don't have a wildlife division here due to political reasons", he says. Indeed, despite the four notified wildlife sanctuaries that form roughly 3.5% of the district's geographical area, there is no wildlife division under the forest department.

Comment: What analogy?  What part of this paragraph are you unclear about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

He is saying that due to politics there is no wildlife division in the forest department despite (in his opinion) the need for such a division. The "gap" is in needed services, that something is not being provided that should.

It would be very similar to saying "Wildlife services have slipped through the cracks".